# remove datarow in datatable through listview control

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, datatable, datarow

i have a problem in delete datarow from the datatable using a button in listview. I am trying to use the button that is selected to delete the row.

```
protected void ShoppingCart_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     String title = ((Label)(ShoppingCart.Items[ShoppingCart.SelectedIndex].FindControl("Title"))).Text;
    DataTable shoppingcart = (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"];
    DataRow[] rows = shoppingcart.Select("Title ='" + title + "'");

    for (int i = rows.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        shoppingcart.Rows.Remove(rows[i]);
    }

    shoppingcart.AcceptChanges();
    ShoppingCart.DataSource = shoppingcart;
    ShoppingCart.DataBind();
}
```

Listview for the cart::

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ShoppingCart" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="ShoppingCart_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        >

<ItemTemplate>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:Label ID="idlabel1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("id") %>' />
</td>
<td>
<asp:Label ID="titlelabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title")%>'></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
<asp:Label ID="pricelabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Price") %>'></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="quantitytb" runat="server" Width="50px" Text='<%#Eval("quantity") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="subtotallabel" runat="server" Text='<%#getsubtotal(decimal.Parse(Eval("Price").ToString()), int.Parse(Eval("quantity").ToString())) %>'></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="-" Font-Names="Web Symbols" CommandName="Select"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</ItemTemplate>

</asp:ListView>
```

the class::

```
public DataTable shoppingCart()
{
    CartTable = new DataTable("cart");

    CartTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
    CartTable.Columns["ID"].AutoIncrement = true;
    CartTable.Columns["ID"].AutoIncrementSeed = 1;

    CartTable.Columns.Add("Title",typeof(String));
    CartTable.Columns.Add("Price");
    CartTable.Columns.Add("quantity");
    CartTable.Columns["quantity"].DataType = typeof(Int32);


    tableRow = CartTable.NewRow();
    tableRow["Title"] = title;
    tableRow["Price"] = price;
    tableRow["quantity"] = quantity;
    CartTable.Rows.Add(tableRow);
    return CartTable;
}
```

I try to delete it but it does not work. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the row from list view then simply remove the item from listview rather than find the datatable then remove and again bind it.

```
if (ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
      ListView1.SelectedItems[0].Remove();
```

As I can understand from your code, you kept the DataTable in session and reading form there and matching with for loop

Why not you get a key value from the list view and then find the row by using datatable.select("xxxxx == yyyyy") and then remove the row.

Comment: i try using both, but there's nothing happen